# Openscad is in array or equivalent

Tags: arrays, list, matrix, vector, openscad

There is something like this on openScad?

```
list = [2, 3];

if(1 in list){
  echo("in");
}else{
  echo("not in");
}
/* or better: */
list = [2, 3];
isin = 1 in list? 100 : 0;
```

Answer (score 7):

For this it's possible to use the built-in `search()` function and check if the result is empty:

```
list = [2, 3, 1];
isin = len(search(1, list)) > 0 ? 100 : 0;
echo(isin);
```

Comment: It always generates a warning if the value isn't in the array. Quite annoying.